# How to create a link within a link in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

**Simple Question:**

Is it possible to create a link to a link to an external document, so that when you click on the first link it takes you immediately to the external document.

**Background**

I have a large master file that has a number of hyperlinks to external supporting files.  A new version of the master file is created each month, and with it new versions of the external files.  While the new version, and the new supporting files are near identical to the previous month, the hyperlinks all reference the prior month's file and need to be revised. As the hyperlinks are scattered throughout the file, and the same file referenced many times, it's a slow process to replace the hyperlinks each month.

As an alternative, I hoped to create a link masterlist, with links to all external documents held in a single sheet, which can quickly and easily be updated each month without the need to search for each of the different references.  All the actual references throughout the master file would just link or formula to this sheet.

The problem I'm finding is this is not creating a "direct link".  Rather thank taking you directly to the external file, it will take you to the master list sheet, where you would need to click again.  While this does the job, it would not be a possible solution as the master file has over 50 sheets and navigating away from the current sheet to link to a related external document would slow down the whole process.

Comment: I added the solution below. The trick is the Hyperlink formula used with the INDIRECT formula.

Comment: If the solution works out, just click the green check-mark near the solution to "accept the answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of a master list is a good way to go. Here is how your idea would work:

Master link Excel Workbook: **master.xlsx** 
Referenced Random Workbook: **BookX.xlsx**

Say your BookX cell B1 is a link, the link master is in cell B1 in master.xlsx.
**The format**:`=HYPERLINK(INDIRECT("[master.xlsx]Sheet1!B1"),"CLICK HERE")`

[image]

***Note:**  It seems that the link must be the actual link in the master list of links. In other words don't use nicknames in the master list as indicated in the image and example above. Nicknames are okay in the random excel file; annotated nickname as "CLICK HERE" above.

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for!  Very helpful.

Comment: @lrmoro Hey, you got it! Glad to help out.